# How can I change the bottom border width on my nav menu tabs?

Tags: web, border, navigationbar, squarespace

I would like to reduce the width of my bottom border on navigation tabs so they don't stick out so far on the right and left.  This is what I have so far for my code, and the line has not adjusted even after adding the `bottom: 5px`. Code is given below

```
#headerNav nav .active a {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color:#ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

Bottom border on nav items:

[image]

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This could probably be done with manipulating the left/right padding and margin values where you'll want to bump up the margin and reduce the padding to preference (that border is in relation to the padding, so less padding, less width of border). Personally, I like the way it looks now as it looks very clean.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I agree - but the client has requested the line be tightened up.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: ah, if they want the menu more condensed, then scrap the bump up margin part and just reduce padding, sorry.